# Nvidia driver updates still showing nvidia-331

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I am using ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. By default ubuntu was using x.orgXserver nouveau but i changed it to Nvidia binary drvier 346 (proprietary, tested).
But after I udated ubuntu through Software Updater, ubuntu changed it back to nouveau driver. And now when i run Software Updater although ubuntu is using nouveau there is these list of updates which seems to be updates for Nvidia proprietary driver, why is that?
these are available udates: 
nvidia binary diriver-version 340.76
nvidia cuda runtime library 
and so on 
should i install these updates? If not and if installing them 
doesn't do anything(considering ubuntu is using xserver) what should 
i do for them not to show in Software updater?
And one more question is nvidia driver still installed on my computer?
If so should i remove it? and how?

`dpkg -l | grep nvidia` output:

```
ii  nvidia-331                                            340.76-0ubuntu0.1                                   amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-331
ii  nvidia-331-uvm                                        340.76-0ubuntu0.1                                   amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-340-uvm
ii  nvidia-340                                            340.76-0ubuntu0.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.76
ii  nvidia-340-uvm                                        340.76-0ubuntu0.1                                   amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-340
ii  nvidia-libopencl1-331                                 340.76-0ubuntu0.1                                   amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-libopencl1-340
ii  nvidia-libopencl1-340                                 340.76-0ubuntu0.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL Driver and ICD Loader library
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-331                                 340.76-0ubuntu0.1                                   amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-340
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-340                                 340.76-0ubuntu0.1                                   amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                          0.6.2                                               amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                       331.20-0ubuntu8                                     amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` commands.

Comment: @Pilot6 ran the command " but the output is grep: and: No such file or directory
grep: dpkg: No such file or directory

Comment: These are TWO separate commands. Not ONE, not FOUR.

Comment: @Pilot6 oops, I was in hurry, didn't see the "and" between them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nvidia-331` packages are left for compatibility only, they just pull `nvidia-340` packages.

You have `nvidia-340` installed. There is nothing to worry about.